# Jsoup: how to combine HTML classes into a product record during iteration

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to scrape a menu like this:-

```
<h3 class="product">Four Cheese Spinach Dip</h3>
<h3 class="specialcallout">Vegetarian</h3>
<h4 class="productdescription">The original, made in-house creamy blend
  of four cheeses, spinach, red pepper and onion. Served warm with fried
  pita chips.</h4>
<h4 class="calories"><span class="productprice">11.99</span>
&nbsp;&nbsp;(620 CALS; serves 2)</h4>
```

I can probably construct a menu object by iterating each class into an array of strings.  Here is the scan to get the menu item name:

```
boolean show_product(String item){
  Elements elems = doc.getElementsByClass(item);
  System.out.println("Num products " + elems.size() + "\n");
 for (Element el : elems) {
    xprint(" * product: <%s>  (%s)", "_",trim(el.text(), 35));
```

Must I have separate routines for product, price, description, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You mustn't do this routine for each attribute, you can do it like this:

```
boolean show_product() {
    Elements elems = doc.getElementsByClass("product");
    System.out.println("Num products " + elems.size() + "\n");
    for (Element el : elems) {
        System.out.printf(" * %s: <%s>  (%s)\n", el.className(), "_", el.text());
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            Element nextSibling = el.nextElementSibling();
            System.out.printf(" * %s: <%s>  (%s)\n", nextSibling.className(), "_", nextSibling.text());
            el = nextSibling;
        }
        Element spanEl = el.select("span").first();
        System.out.printf(" * %s: <%s>  (%s)\n", spanEl.className(), "_", spanEl.text());
    }
    return true;
}
```

Also the HTML class is combined into the product records and the other attributes.

Comment: Aha, I thought a sibling was only applicable within a tag but the @m3n2a2 solution worked. Here is a console print:-                        Scraper1...
 
    Num Records 40

     * name: <_>  (Arduino LilyPad LED Micro (Green 5pcs))
     * model: <_>  (0219-SPF-1100222)
     * stock: <_>  (In Stock)
     * price: <_>  ($5.39)
     * name: <_>  (Arduino Motor Shield Rev3 (Retail) (4.5V-46V 2A/ch)     (from arduino.cc))
     * model: <_>  (1655-ARD-7815011)
     * stock: <_>  (In Stock)
     * price: <_>  ($29.79 CAD)